# WP API and JS : Cannot read property 'wp:featuredmedia' of undefined

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

I write a component to display a list WP posts on a page build with nuxt.js and I just can not display the featured image.

**The Vue Component**

```
<template>
  <div class="references__grid">
    <div class="references__item" v-for="item in references">
        <h3><nuxt-link :to="slugToUrl(item.slug)"><h2 class="is-title">{{ item.title }}</h2></nuxt-link></h3>
        <div v-html="item.excerpt"></div>
        <div>{{ item.image }}</div>
        <strong class="more"><nuxt-link :to="slugToUrl(item.slug)">Lire la suite</nuxt-link></strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**The request**

```
  getReferences() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request.defaults.baseURL = this.baseUrl;
      request.get(`posts?categories=46&per_page=6&_embedded`).then(response => {
        const data = [...response.data];
        if (response.status === 200 && response.data.length > 0) {
          const filtered = {
            total: response.headers["x-wp-total"],
            totalPages: response.headers["x-wp-totalpages"],
            data: data.map(item => ({
              id: item.id,
              title: item.title.rendered,
              content: item.content.rendered,
              excerpt: item.excerpt.rendered,
              slug: item.slug,
              image: item._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].media_details.sizes.full.source_url
            }))
          };
          resolve(filtered);
        } else {
          reject(response);
        }
      });
    });
  },
```

The WP Api seems ok: [https://www.agencedebord.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=46&per_page=61&_embed](https://www.agencedebord.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=46&per_page=6&_embed)

The error message:

> ERROR
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>
> - server-bundle.js:1525 filtered.data.data.map.item
>     server-bundle.js:1525:56
> - Array.map
> - server-bundle.js:1519 >__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_axios___default.a.get.then    .response
>     server-bundle.js:1519:24
> - next_tick.js:160 process._tickCallback
>     internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7

So why item._embedded is undefined?
There is no problem for item.id or item.slug... any clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I did not use "_embed" but I add a new endpoint following this answer : [Get Image URL instead of Attachment Id in Rest API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271448/get-image-url-instead-of-attachment-id-in-rest-api)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is sometimes `item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']` is returning `undefined`, you can confirm you get that by `console.log(item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'])`, the solution for that by wrapping it in if condition, if it not undefined to proceed `if(item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']){ return let imageUrl = item._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].media_details.sizes.full.source_url
 } else { return null}`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the request url is not correct, you should use _embed not _embedded

So it will be `request.get(`posts?categories=46&per_page=6&_embed`)`

Otherwise, the _embedded part will be missing in the json response.

Answer (score 0):

I had one post that was giving this error. I had the if/else setup properly but it was still erroring. I went to the problem post and resaved the featured image and also changed to the ajax to load .full.source_url instead of .medium.source_url and that fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

*I imported some photos from another wordpress. some of them had not featured images yet they somehow acting like they have. (has_post_thumbnail() was acting same way and returns true for that posts)*

My solution is checking if they 'really' have thumbnail:

```
if(post.featured_media == 0 || post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details == undefined){
    imageSource = null;
}
else{
    imageSource = post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.full.source_url;
}
```